# Send Video to Server

Tags: php, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to send video to server. What I am doing is I am converting the video into a "**ToBase64String**" and sending to my server via **JObject**. My problem is the sending of the video is too slow about 20 to 30 mins depending on the file size and  connection to server speed. How can I improve the speed or is there a better way to send a video to a server. I am using Xamarin and PHP. I am also using **ffmpeg** to convert the video into a smaller size when saving the video to the server's hard drive. I think the sending of the base64string is fast the processing of the video(My PHP) is slow because when I use break in my code the app is waiting for the response from my server(**crresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode**). I think it is either the conversion of the video using ffmpeg or the creation of the video itself **file_put_contents**

Xamarin Code (this is where I convert and send the video)

```
byte[] crVideoData = File.ReadAllBytes(crvideo);
crvid = Convert.ToBase64String(crVideoData);

JObject crjson = new JObject
{
   { "Video", crvid }
}

HttpClient crclient = new HttpClient();
var crresponse = await crclient.PostAsync(crlink, new StringContent(crjson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, crcontentType));

if (crresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     await conn.QueryAsync<CAFTable>("UPDATE tblCaf SET LastSync = ? WHERE CAFNo = ?", DateTime.Parse(current_datetime), crcafNo);
}
```

PHP code (this is where I receive and decode the base64string)

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

$Video = $json_obj->Video;
$ContactID = $json_obj->ContactID;

$video_decode = base64_decode($Video);
$video_filename = __DIR__ . '/uploads/'. $CAF . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
$video_dbfilename = './uploads/'. $CAF . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
$save_video = file_put_contents($video_filename, $video_decode);

if(file_exists($video_filename)) {
   $temp_video_filename = __DIR__ . '/tmp/'. $CAFNo . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
   exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video_filename.' -c:v libx264 '.$temp_video_filename.' 2>&1');
   unlink($video_filename);
   rename($temp_video_filename, $video_filename);
}
```

Comment: Don't make wild guesses about performance problems.  Get hard data about where the bottleneck is by timing your code and fix it.  And you should not need to encode a video stream to upload it - you can just send a byte[].

Comment: @Jason how can I send it via JSON object

Comment: I would suggest you send a byte[] data rather than using base64

Comment: @G.hakim can you remote my computer? there is an error when I tried to  send a byte via JObject?

Comment: Sure we can do that tomorrow

Comment: @G.hakim I solved the error I can now send the byte not the base64string now the problem really is the speed of transmission any suggestions?

Comment: Well, i would suggest you see to it that it is async, doesn't have unnecessary declarations and usage of objects that are not necessary then i would suggest you do the same at API side and see how the performance gets

Comment: I think the API is the problem i benched marked the speed when uploading a less than 1mb video it takes about 1-2 minutes for the file to be created the byte array has been sent almost instantly the file creation takes too long

Comment: @G.hakim bro the file_put_contents is taking to long how can I improve this?

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to create the video?

Comment: @G.hakim the code is the PHP part